# Science fiction series where humans (from another world) find the Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship, space-exploration

The plot had humans from a different system that suffered a catastrophic event on their home world, if I remember correctly.

It was implied that their ancestors seeded life in other planets too (or just separated themselves into 4 or 5 different planets?) or something like that, so they leave their system to find if their mythology has any truth. During the last episode they find their cousins... our Earth

It wasn't something very popular I guess but it was a decent production.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Hopefully we can help with your question. As this particular theme is pretty common (think Battlestar Galactica), is there anything else you can help provide in narrowing down what it might be? For example, how long ago might "some years" be?  5? 10? Longer?  Was it in English (or perhaps dubbed?). Did you see it overseas or in the U.S.? Was it animated or live-action?  Any detail no matter how trivial it might seem can help. Again, welcome to the site. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like Battlestar Galactica. Probably the original

Comment: hmm, I have seen pretty much all major sci-fi movies and series and Galactica was one of the very first but not the one I am looking for. I remember that when I first heard of  the name of the series, it was totally new to me so it must be something not as popular as Galactica. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You could be right. BG was initially my thought as well. Hence, my comment. But, the question indicates the survivors don't find out it is Earth until the last episode. In BG, the destination is known relatively quickly. I think this may be a similar, but different, series. We'll see though. :-)

Comment: At some point during the series they had an ongoing war against other species. Then I remember an episode where all crew and passengers in a huge spaceship are gathered in a big hall. Their quest for earth was something you could say it was their religion, they didn't know for sure there was actually a planet as mentioned in their old history.

Comment: the series were definitely in English and based on what I can remember it was modern enough in cgi so it must be in 00s or later. I saw it online maybe youtube. One thing that might help is that I found about this series while watching Space Above and Beyond.

Comment: If you have found it on youtube then maybe it's one of these fanfictions like Battlestar 1999 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpB9NbPNNhE).

Comment: One very important twist I forgot is that the whole story is set somewhere in the very distant past from our own perspective and during the last episode the spaceship they had is almost destroyed and humans used shuttles to land on earth. They had to abandon all technology behind and this was the hint they were our own ancestors, living on earth in a primitive way.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the original (1978) [Battlestar Galactica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica) TV series. It has a kid and a robotic dog.

What you're describing is the original Battlestar Galactica series.

Comment: I'm not sure what the kid and dog have to do with it.

Comment: Possible details that might stick out at them, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It is the 2004 Battlestar Galactica series more than likely because what is described the last episode they find Earth. The Galactica's last jump broke its back and everything else fits into place. The original series never found Earth
, but in the first episode of Galactica 1980 they found our Earth.